# Publishing .fig files without having them appear on screen

Tags: matlab, publish

I have some code that generates a number of MATLAB figures. At the end of my program I want to publish these figures in a report. I have a script, which is passed to publish(), that uses openfig() to include the figures in the document.

This causes these figures to flash up on the screen. This is particularly annoying when I am opening figures inside a loop using a combination of close and snapnow. I've tried making these figures invisible using

```
openfig(PathToFigure, 'new', 'invisible')
```

This stops the image appearing on the screen but also stops it appearing in the report.

Is there a way of including .fig files in the report without having them appear on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the figure with `f=openfig(PathToFigure, 'new', 'invisible')`. Then move the figure off-screen by setting its `Position` property (perhaps to something with negative values for the left and bottom pixels), set its `Visible` property to `on`, call `snapnow`. Delete the figure.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend setting their visibility to 'off' when you create those figures with
`f = figure('Visible','off');`

Comment: That also seems to stop the figure appearing in report, even with openfig set to 'visible'. Am I even using the right function for this? I need some way of keeping the figure invisible but still including its contents in the report.